# Vite handleHotUpdate ctx.server.moduleGraph empty?

Tags: javascript, vite

I'm writing a little Vite plugin that generates a virtual module based off of a configuration file. This is working so far. Next I'd like to hot reload the resulting virtual module when the underlying file changes. I was going to use `ctx.server.reloadModule` to trigger a module reload. However, I'm running into an issue with all the Maps in `ctx.server.moduleGraph` being empty and thus `ctx.server.moduleGraph.findModuleById` not returning anything. This is true regardless of which file I touch/change.

I'm sure I am misunderstanding something or making some clowny mistake, but all my googling turned up nothing.

This is my `handleHotUpdate` implementation:

```js
    handleHotUpdate(ctx) {
      if (ctx.file.endsWith(esphomeWebConfigFile)) {
        // Not sure if I need to use module ID or resolved module ID here
        const mod = ctx.server.moduleGraph.getModuleById(cssModuleId);
        // Bot doesn't really matter anyway, because this here turns up with an
        // empty Map!
        console.log(ctx.server.moduleGraph.idToModuleMap);

        // ctx.server.reloadModule(mod);
        return [];
      }
    },
```

Here's also my full plugin code, in case other parts are relevant:

```js
function esphomeWebConfigVirtualModules() {
  const cssModuleId = 'virtual:custom.css';
  const moduleIds = [cssModuleId];
  function resolveId(id) {
    return `\0${id}`;
  }

  const esphomeWebConfigFile = 'esphome-web.json';
  const esphomeWebConfigPath = esphomeWebConfigFile;
  let esphomeWebConfig = {};
  if (fs.existsSync(esphomeWebConfigPath)) {
    esphomeWebConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(esphomeWebConfigPath))
  }
  function generateCssModule() {
    const o = esphomeWebConfig.css || {};
    return `body { \n${Object.keys(o).map(k => `  ${k}: ${o[k]};\n`).join('')}}`;
  }

  return {
    name: 'esphome-web-config-virtual-modules-plugin',
    resolveId(id) {
      if (moduleIds.includes(id)) {
        return resolveId(id);
      }
    },
    handleHotUpdate(ctx) {
      if (ctx.file.endsWith(esphomeWebConfigFile)) {
        // Not sure if I need to use module ID or resolved module ID here
        const mod = ctx.server.moduleGraph.getModuleById(cssModuleId);
        // Bot doesn't really matter anyway, because this here turns up with an
        // empty Map!
        console.log(ctx.server.moduleGraph.idToModuleMap);

        // ctx.server.reloadModule(mod);
        return [];
      }
    },
    load(id) {
      if (id === resolveId(cssModule)) {
        return generateCssModule();
      }
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. There were two major and one minor flaw in my approach.

1. The moduleGraph was empty, because I didn't have an actual client session. You need to actually hit your dev server for it to bootstrap and populate the moduleGraph. That seems obvious in retrospect, but when I was testing I was just re-writing my files without actually connecting a user agent to the dev server.
2. I read the esphome-web.json file during plugin instantiation and return the cached value in the `load()` function. This is so I can have multiple virtual modules depend on this one JSON file (there are some other peculiarities in my code as a result of that). But this means that even if I trigger a hot reload of the virtual module, that it will just load with the original cached version of esphome-web.json. In addition to triggering the hot reload from handleHotReload I also need to actually reload the file. The Vite documentation recommends using the arguments supplied `read()` function for avoiding some platform dependent race conditions.
3. The minor issue is that `server.reloadModule` is unnecessary. Simply adding the module instance to the returned array will correctly trigger a hot reload.

With all of that said, here's my now working code:

```
async handleHotUpdate({server, read, modules, file}) {
  if (file.endsWith(esphomeWebConfigFile)) {
    // recache JSON
    esphomeWebConfig = JSON.parse(await read());

    // getModuleById requires the resolved module ID
    const mod = server.moduleGraph.getModuleById(resolveId(cssModuleId));

    // Add the virtual module to the list of modules requiring reloading
    return [...modules, mod];
  }
},
```